# Unable to Login to iOS Account from CodeNameOne

Tags: ios, codenameone

IDE: Eclipse
Desktop OS : Ubuntu
Simulator 
Device : iOS

Hi Team,

I want to generate new Certificate for iOS app. I also has valid itunesconnect apple id. But while login into it I am getting below error on the screen.
"REST Request failed due to internal CLI failure..."

Attaching the screenshot for reference. Kindly look into this issue and provide solution as early as possible. We are not able to build the iOS app due to this issue.

[image]

Regards
Ashish

Comment: Can you try disabling 2-factor authentication on your account? 
Do you have a device associated with your apple account?

Comment: Is possible to continue with 2-Factor Authentication? I am not able to disable 2-factor auth from apple account.

Comment: Yes but you need to setup a trusted device on which you can follow with the 2-factor authentication

Comment: is there a solution for this issue. I have encounter same problem. How can we make windows machine which I use for development as trusted device on Apple account. As of now we can't deactivate 2-factor authentication. Please advise.