# Issue using Codename One iOS Certificate Wizard, getting error "REST request failed"

Tags: ios, codenameone

I have been trying to generate an iOS certificate from the Codename One Control Center, launched from Intellij. Every time I submit my apple iOS developer credentials, and then input the 2 factor authentication code, it returns with this error:

`REST request failed due to internal CLI failure. See server error log.c5307525-1805-4360-d4ca9d46cad0`

I enrolled in the Apple Developer Program, and I believe I've agreed to all of the Apple Developer agreements and such, and I have exactly one device registered, as well as that one device set as the trusted device, so it receives the 2 factor authentication notifications. I'm also not sure where I am expected to be able to see the "Server error log" as I have searched around for that.

I've only been able to find 2 other cases that seem similar to mine but neither give me a clear idea of what the problem is or how to fix it. They do however seem to resolve their problems. I really don't have any more ideas as to what the problem could be.

[Codename One IOS signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66229081/codename-one-ios-signing)

[Unable to Login to iOS Account from CodeNameOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631441/unable-to-login-to-ios-account-from-codenameone)

Another odd thing about this problem is that usually I get this error after being prompted to input the 2-factor authentication code, but sometimes I'm never prompted to input the code before getting the error, yet I will still receive the 2-factor authentication code text message on my phone despite there being nowhere to use it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after looking around a bit further, I was finally able to find a git issue post that seemed similar to mine, and at the very end of the thread (linked below), someone mentioned that you need to be signed into that apple id on the device, not just have it as a trusted device. My iOS phone was showing up in the account because I was logged into the Apple Developer App, but this is not enough. Thanks for helping.

https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2779

Answer (score 1):

I have made some updates to the certificate wizard to try to work around this issue.  Please give it another try.  If you run into another problem, please post the error message again, and I'll look it up in the logs.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not seem to work either. This latest error was "REST request failed due to internal CLI failure. See server error log.2bdd1d98-271c-468c-b249-6280dbe7d246"

Comment: Is it possible that having a different name on the apple id and the codename one account would cause this problem?